# Create New Database Entry in Rails via Posting JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This should be so freaking simple, I don't know why I can't get it figured out. Basically, all I want to do is create a guestbook for my page. The Model Posts has a body and message attribute. All I want to do is post a JSON with that information, and have it saved to the database.

The pastebin with the code is here http://pastebin.com/JMvNM4E0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your strong parameters to this:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:author, :body)
```

You're also not saving the `Post` as pointed out by @zakwan below.

You need to call `@post.save` or you could use #create

```
@post = Posts.create(post_params)
```

Comment: then `@post.save!` to save in DB

Comment: This worked. I do have one followup question, how do I make rails NOT refresh the page after the POST? It tries to redirect it to a view.

Comment: Add `return false` to the end of your `@savePost` method